# error when trying to use speakeasy from a react-native project

Tags: react-native, speakeasy

> error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `crypto` from
>   `myproject/node_modules/speakeasy/index.js`: Module
>   does not exist in the module map\n\nThis might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try
>   the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman
>   watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf
>   node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr
>   $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`."

Following the suggested steps doesn't seem to do any good.

Also tried to `yarn add react-native-crypto` but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using rn-nodeify but limiting it to specific modules.

As described https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify, one can run `rn-nodeify --install --hack` and int takes care of the crypto lib among others.

Answer (score 0):

Since this package is originally for `Node.js`, therefore they are not including inherited packages like `crypto` , `util` and `url` from the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/) itself in the [dependencies](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy/blob/cb58351b7eb829719dbee2df2ede53d97721ef6d/package.json#L40) in `package.json`

Since some of them are deprecated therefore you can't use it as is.

- **Crypto** (deprecated)

  > This package is no longer supported and has been deprecated. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name.
- **Util** (link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util))
- **Url** ( link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url))